# Codeigniter blog: display post title in comments table

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am working on a **blog application** in Codeigniter 3.1.8 and Bootstrap 4.

There is a *posts* table and a *comments* table in the database. I have displayed all the comments in a Bootstrap 4 table. I want to display the *title* of the post each comment belongs to, instead of the post's *id*:

[image]

My Comments controller:

```
class Comments extends CI_Controller {

  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Static_model');
    $this->load->model('Posts_model');
    $this->load->model('Categories_model');
    $this->load->model('Comments_model');
  }

  public function index() {
    $data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();
    $data['categories'] = $this->Categories_model->get_categories();
    $data['number_of_categories'] = $this->Categories_model->get_num_rows();
    $data['posts'] = $this->Posts_model->get_all_posts();
    $data['number_of_posts'] = $this->Posts_model->get_num_rows();
    $data['comments'] = $this->Comments_model->get_all_comments();

    $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('dashboard/comments');
    $this->load->view('partials/footer');
  }
}
```

In the **Comments_model** model I have:

```
public function get_all_comments(){
    $this->db->select('comments.*');
    $this->db->order_by('comments.id', 'DESC');
    //$this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
    $this->db->join('posts', 'posts.id = comments.post_id');        
    $query = $this->db->get('comments');
    return $query->result();
}
```

In the view:

```
<tbody>
  <?php foreach ($comments as $index => $comment): ?>
  <tr id="<?php echo $comment->id; ?>">
    <td><?php echo $index + 1; ?></td>
    <td class="w-25"><?php echo $comment->comment; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $comment->name; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $posts['title']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo nice_date($comment->created_at, 'D, M d, Y'); ?></td>
    <td>Aproved</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <?php endforeach ?>
</tbody>
```

While `<?php echo $posts->id; ?>` displays the posts id, which i do not need in the view, the line  results in an

> Message: Undefined index: title error.

What is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

`get_all_comments` method should be like this : *add `posts.title` in select also*

```
public function get_all_comments()
{
   $this->db->select('comments.*,posts.title as post_title');
   $this->db->order_by('comments.id', 'DESC');
   //$this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
   $this->db->join('posts', 'posts.id = comments.post_id');        
   $query = $this->db->get('comments');
   return $query->result();
}
```

Replace it

```
<td><?php echo $posts['title']; ?></td>
```

with

```
<td><?php echo $comment->post_title; ?></td>
```

Comment: What should the view look? `<td><?php echo $posts['title']; ?></td>` gives `Undefined variable: posts` error.

Comment: $posts['title']; changes to $comment->post_title; see my answer